# Print a completely processed $form

Tags: 8, forms, paragraphs

Is there a hook one can use on, say, a node edit page that will print the $form array after it has been completely processed? I'm customizing a Paragraph edit form inside a Node edit form and thus altering the Paragraphs Field Widget -> Subform. The subform's '#process' key contains a further function to execute:

[image]

But if, say, I print the $form var inside hook_node_form_alter, this #process still has not executed.

The larger problem is that my subform contains a custom submit handler that is not being called when I submit the subform and I'd like to print the entire form array after processing to ensure the submit handler is actually there in the $form array. If the problem of custom submit handlers not firing inside subforms sounds familiar, let me know

**EDIT**

Relative to the larger problem, this is what my embedded form looks like after all processing completes (i.e. printed in an #after_build)

[image]

Comment: When I've altered paragraph forms in the past I've used [hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter/8.2.x), e.g. `my_module_field_widget_entity_reference_paragraphs_form_alter()`. I can't tell for certain, but it doesn't sound like that's what you're doing - I think you'll find it's easier to work with.

Comment: I'm using hook_field_widget_entity_reference_paragraphs_form_alter which is working great for getting the form to display the way I want. In essence, I am placing another form within this paragraphs (e.g. the widget has its own paragraph subform and another form). This other form has a custom submit handler that is supposed to fire: '#submit' => [[$this, 'updateSegmentSet']], but when I print debug in that function, it never appears to fire (the form does submit and return empty ajax data though)

Comment: Basically you could use any hook in the theming level because the result of processing ends up in form elements ready to be rendered. Within the form building process you could add a `#after_build` callback to the widget element. Probably the easiest way to debug these things is to set a breakpoint in Xdebug in the form builder and step through the code to see why it doesn't fire.

Comment: One thing I've done is debug around `public function executeSubmitHandlers` specifically the line `$handlers = $form_state->getSubmitHandlers()` and noted that the custom handler isn't even there, only handlers that apply to the greater Node Edit form (since its the entire Node Edit form thats submitted back to the form builder)

Comment: Could the issue be that the embedded form isnt wrapped in a <form> container? So when `<input type='submit'` is pressed, it bubbles all the way up to the greater form and ignores the custom submit handlers attached? What's strange is that this type of ajax functionality for adding/removing elements from a Node Edit form is commonplace and the submit buttons that power it don't appear to be wrapped in `<form>'s`

Comment: @4k4 I’ve used `#after_build` and confirmed that in `$form[‘field’][‘widget’][0][‘settings’][‘decision’][‘decision_select’][‘update’]` my custom submit handler is appended along with custom ajax callback. Note that the parent `decision` is of `#type => ‘details’`. I've edited my original question with this embedded forms fully processed array to see if any value makes sense as to why the custom submit handler isnt called